# How can I add a module to a project in VS 2017 enterprise?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I'm taking a VB course that uses the 6th edition of Gaddis (2012). It says that to add a module to the project I must do the following;

[image]

However, this option is missing in my install of VS 2017 Enterprise. Is my install messed up, or has this functionality changed since Gaddis 6th came out, or am I missing an installed piece? If my installation is incomplete, which feature should I install?

Comment: The selection of Project Item templates changes in every release of Visual Studio to help advertise whatever new features came out in that edition. Use the search box in the top right corner to search for "module".

Comment: Or just create an empty `.vb` file and put "`Module Foo`" and "`End Module`" in it and it's the same thing.

Comment: @Dai, tried that, only got results for cpp

Comment: You need to have the VB project selected in Solution Explorer for the Add New Project Item dialog to suggest VB items. If you're seeing C++ items then you're in a C++ project or you're in the "New File" or "Add New Solution Item" (not Project Item) dialogs.

Comment: @Dai if you mark as answer I will accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selection of Project Item templates changes in every release of Visual Studio to help advertise whatever new features came out in that edition. Use the search box in the top right corner to search for "module".

You need to have the VB project selected in Solution Explorer for the Add New Project Item dialog to suggest VB items. If you're seeing C++ items then you're in a C++ project or you're in the "New File" or "Add New Solution Item" (not Project Item) dialogs:

#### File > New File

[image]

#### New Solution Item

[image]

#### New Project Item (Visual Basic)

[image]